# Python groupby returning NaN averaged values after creating bins

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe that consist in hourly values of alpha (wind shear) for 2014, 2015 and 2016.

```
   Year Month Day Hour alpha

0 2014    8     1   0   0.275673
1 2014    8     1   1   0.365437
2 2014    8     1   2   0.431942
3 2014    8     1   3   0.450911
4 2014    8     1   4   0.348400
5 2014    8     1   5   0.526142
```

I'm trying to get the mean value of alpha during the day (8-19hrs) and night (0-8 and 19-23hrs) by creating bins and later averaging through the groupby function:

```
bins = [0,8,19,23]
df_alpha['Hour-binned'] = pd.cut(df_alpha['Hour'],bins,include_lowest=True)
df_alpha = df_alpha[['Year','Month','Day', "Hour-binned", "alpha",'Hour']]
df_alpha.groupby(['Year','Month','Day',"Hour-binned"]).mean()
```

But this results in NaN results for the average alpha. Am I using the .cut() function in a wrong way?

```
                                      alpha     Hour
 Year   Month   Day     Hour-binned         
 2014   1         1      (-0.001, 8.0]  NaN     NaN
                         (8.0, 19.0]    NaN     NaN
                         (19.0, 23.0]   NaN     NaN
                  2      (-0.001, 8.0]  NaN     NaN
                         (8.0, 19.0]    NaN     NaN
```

Comment: i dont get all NaN from your existing code , seems like working for me, can you add expected output , there is also no Day 2 in your input so you may want to relook at that to make it less conusing :)

Comment: This is the complete dataframe https://1drv.ms/u/s!AohwPPUAn-x7kLteqsZK51fiphVnSg?e=WABZXI

Answer (score 2):

You can create a boolean value to indicate nighttime hours.  If this is false, that means day time.  Then add 'Night' to your groupby function and unstack it so that the day and night averages are side by side for a given date.

```
>>> result = (
        df
        .assign(Night=df['Hour'].lt(8) | df['Hour'].gt(19))
        .groupby(['Year', 'Month', 'Day', 'Night'])['alpha']
        .mean()
        .unstack('Night')
        .rename(columns={False: 'Day', True: 'Night'})
    )
    result.columns.name = None
    >>> result
                     Day     Night 
Year Month Day                    
2014 8     1    0.218008  0.416217
           2    0.170137  0.439346
           3    0.191906  0.311010
           4    0.114431  0.250438
           5    0.190394  0.307582
...                  ...       ...
2015 7     26   0.443886  0.540883
           27   0.298527  0.343694
           28   0.171768  0.389598
           29   0.133082  0.396037
           30   0.064459  0.339240

[313 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks Alexander, it worked! And even better than my original idea. Nevertheless, any idea why the bins were not functional?

Comment: No problem. You can also rename the columns 'Day' and 'Night' if you wish.